# How to add an element at the begining of a linked list without replacing the current first element?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have the following struct Element:

```
typedef struct struct_element{
    Tache t;
    struct struct_element *suivant;
}Element;
typedef Element* Liste;
```

I'm trying to create a function "ajoutdeb" which is supposed to create a new element, and make the current first element of the list the next one of the new element.That way the new element will be placed at the begining of the linked-list. Here is my implementation of it:

```
void ajoutdeb(Liste* l, Tache t)
{
    Element e; 
    e.t = t;
    e.suivant = *l;
    *l = &e;
}
```

My problem is that the next element of the new element is itself. What's wrong with the logic of my function ?

Exemple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct{
  int no; /*le nom de la tache*/
  int duree; /* la duree de la tache*/
  int nbPred;     /* le nombre effectif de predecesseur de la tache*/
  int pred[16];  /*le tableau des predecesseurs*/
  char titre[256];   /*le titre de la tache*/
}Tache;

typedef struct struct_element{
    Tache t;
    struct struct_element *suivant;
}Element;

typedef Element* Liste;

void ajoutdeb(Liste* l, Tache t)
{
    Element e;
    e.t = t;
    e.suivant = *l;
    *l = &e;
}

int main()
{
    int nb;
    Liste liste = NULL;

    Tache t1 = {
            .titre = "Init",
            .no = 0
    };
    Tache t2 = {
            .titre = "Deuxième",
            .no = 1
    };

    ajoutdeb(&liste, t1);
    ajoutdeb(&liste, t2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem is that the variable `e` lives on the stack and therefore will not be accessible after the function ends.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. The problem is within the shown code, but to explain the problem we need a common context to refer to.

Comment: The new code you show shouldn't have the problem you describe. How do you check for the issue?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like by allocating e dynamically my problem is solved

Comment: Then please don't modify the code in the question. It makes the question totally worthless to anybody else looking at it, since it doesn't actually have the problem described.

Comment: Also since I'm allocating it dynamically, if I free the current first element using "free", will it free all the next element also allocated dynamically or not ?

Comment: No, each node is allocated separately. But do look at [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) and get rid of your `typedef` -- which is likely causing confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `ajoutdeb()` function, you need the return-type to be able to indicae success or failure of adding a new node to the calling function. Making the return type a pointer to node is a good option. On failure, you can return `NULL` and on success, you can return the new head node for the list.

Your `ajoutdeb()` function needs to:

1. allocate and VALIDATE storage for a new node;
2. fully initialize the value and pointer to that node; and
3. insert the new node as the new head of your list (called *forward-chaining* the nodes)

Since you allocate for a new node, you must ***validate*** that the allocation succeeded before proceeding further in your function. If the allocation fails, return `NULL` to indicate failure. If it succeeds you can complete adding the node to your list.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
Element *ajoutdeb(Element **l, Tache t)
{
    Element *e = malloc (sizeof *e);
    
    if (!e) {               /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-e");
        return NULL;        /* return NULL on failure */
    }
    
    e->t = t;               /* fully initialize new node */
    e->suivant = NULL;
    
    e->suivant = *l;        /* make e->suivant point to list */
    *l = e;                 /* update list pointer to current */
    
    return *l;      /* return new head node on success */
}
```

(**note:** avoid typedeffing pointers. That hides a level of indirection. While in 60 lines of code it may be easy to look at the top of the screen to recall that `Liste` is actually type `Element*`, but that becomes increasingly difficult 6000 lines down when dealing with many types of pointers and levels of indirection. See [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers))

You may want to examine [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) for the other details of implementation and then look at [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) for the benefit of using a `tail` pointer to provide O(1) insertions at the end of the list when your needs change.

Let me know if you have further questions.